# sum of reciprocal of roots

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

Say we are given $$\alpha \tan \sqrt x =(1+\alpha) \sqrt x$$ where $\alpha > 0$ ad are after its positive roots. In particular, I am interested in estimating the following $$S=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x_j(1+\alpha)^2-\alpha},$$
where $x_j$ is the j-th positive root.
I know by graphical inspection that the roots are such that $(j-1)^2\pi^2<x_j<(j-\frac12)^2\pi^2$ hence I have an upper and a lower bound for the sum where for the summations I use Cauchy stuff. The problem is that the bounds I get are quite bad: numerically, the lower bounds is not good, since, again graphically, I observe that the roots are closer to $(j-\frac12)^2\pi^2$ than to $(j-1)^2\pi^2$ for a wide range of values of $\alpha$.

***Here is the question***: can one find exact values for $S$ in terms of $\alpha$? If not can we find tight bounds on $S$ (tighter than mine).